# How to create several smaller lists that contain specified indices based on a larger list in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have a list with nested lists that are of different size. I want to look for those that contain 3 Objects and split them into 3 different lists with the following format:
from [x,y,z] to [x,y], [x,z], [y,z]

I already tried the append function but that doesn't seem to work

```
edges3_2000= [[980065855, 981668537], [979913095, 979913834],
 [968276549, 974397900, 982082188],[976522303, 980117189],
 [935286395, 979789696, 981925831], [932339048, 971089121]]

edges5_2000 =[]
for sublist in edges3_2000:           
        if len(sublist) == 3:
            edges5_2000.append(sublist[0][1])
            edges5_2000.append(sublist[0][2])
            edges5_2000.append(sublist[1][2])
```

This yields the error message: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Which line causes the error? Try adding some `print()` statements to see what is going on. For example what does `print(sublist)` and `print(sublist[0])` show? Is this what you expect?

Comment: It appears that either `sublist` or one of its elements is an integer.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: @Prune, *"it appears that..."* why not clear? `sublist` is a list of integers. OP has example given with the code itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sublist == [968276549, 974397900, 982082188]` then `sublist[0] == 968276549` and `sublist[0][1]` tries to subscript an integer.

Change the append lines to:

```
edges5_2000.append([sublist[0], sublist[1]])
edges5_2000.append([sublist[0], sublist[2]])
edges5_2000.append([sublist[1], sublist[2]])
```

Comment: Works perfectly, but I just figured that there is also a list included that contains 105 values. Is there a way to automate this whole process, following the same idea as with the 3 values?

Comment: Post it as a new question and explain what your expected results are. It's not obvious what the "same idea" is when you go from 3 values to 105.